# Composer workflow: How to update composer.lock when I changed a dependence

Tags: php, development-environment, composer-php

The project is set-up via `composer.phar install --prefer-source` and contains quite some modules which are kept in git.

I manage all these modules and their git repositories in my IDE (PhpStorm) and so might commit some changes to some of the modules in the `vendor/` folder - directly to the source git repository.

How can I make sure now, that my co-workers get my recent module version when doing a `composer.phar install` (`composer.lock` is in the repo)?

If I make a local `composer.phar update` it looks like the `composer.lock` is not updated, because I already have the latest version (as I just made the commit directly in the `vendor` folder)

Comment: If you point to a tag, the version will not change and composer does not see a reason to update it. If that is the case, you should increment the version number when you change package definition.

Comment: I point to "*". The problem is how to generate an updated `composer.lock`

Comment: Is not updated, because you are not pushing changes. After you change the library from vendor/ dir, you should push the changes to remote. After that composer will detect new version and will act accordingly. And I suggest to use "dev-develop" or "dev-master" instead of "*" as require, so you can have more control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Commit the changes in the modules repos you've updated.
2. Push the changes to all respective remote repos.
3. Tag the new changes with appropriate versions.
4. Run `composer update vendor1/package1 vendor2/package2` (or just `composer update` if you don't need to be explicit).
5. Commit and push the updated `composer.lock` file.
6. Your co-workers need to pull the updated `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` (install latest package versions from lock file).

If you have specified versions restrictions such as `"vendor/package": "3.5.*"` in your `composer.json` and you have tagged a new version like `3.6.0` you will need to update your `composer.json` file accordingly before step `4.`.

---

P.S. It is very good you use such a workflow with `--prefer-source`. Please do not use `*` or `dev-master` version restrictions in your `composer.json`. I would recommend always use versions even if they are in the zero major version range (`0.X.X`).